# Custom systemd process on debian slow to start up

Tags: debian, systemd

I'm setting up rtpproxy on a debian 8.3 server through the default package available in the repos.  The package comes with the sysvinit script still, and I want to use a keepalive so I'm trying to set up a systemd service file.  I'm borrowing [from their github repo a bit](https://github.com/sippy/rtpproxy/tree/master/rpm) from what seems like their Fedora setup.  I also chose to forego their socket/service type setup in favor of the more traditional rtpproxy method of defining the socket in the Exec command.  Here's what I'm using:

```
[Unit]
Description=A symmetric RTP proxy
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=rtpproxy
Group=rtpproxy
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/rtpproxy
PIDFile=/var/run/rtpproxy/rtpproxy.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rtpproxy -s $CONTROL_SOCK -p /var/run/rtpproxy/rtpproxy.pid $EXTRA_OPTS
Restart=always
TimeoutStopSec=30s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Variables `$CONTROL_SOCK` and `$EXTRA_OPTS` are defined in `/etc/default/rtpproxy`.

While this does work, it takes a while for the process to finish starting up only if the system has been rebooted (it seems).  If it's been running and I restart the process, it's quick.  How can I determine why this process is taking so long to start up on system boot?

Answer (score 0):

Add a suitable `-d` option to tune up the debug level, and then you'll see in the logs which step takes long.